# DialogField lost value when set property RunOn to Server in Report AX

Tags: axapta

When set property to "RunOn" to Server in ReportRun AX, all Dialogfields in the dialog loses value.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not save/unsave all your dialog fields in the `pack` and `unpack` methods.
The methods are used for passing the values from server to client (and back) for use in the dialog.

An easy fix may be to add the method:

```
protected boolean canSwapBetweenCS()
{
    return false;
}
```

This will make the dialog use a somewhat slower client/server communication.